# Reduce Ansible list of objects to a single string of concatenated object values

Tags: ansible

I am trying to parse the output of `elasticache_facts` ansible module, to extract the IPS and the ports of the memcached nodes in a string of the form "addr1: port1 addr2:port2 ..."(I want to store this string in a configmap to be used in an app).

Basically I want to take two fields "address" and "port" from a list of dicts like this:

```
list1:
- endpoint: 
    address: "addr1"
    port: "port1"
- endpoint: 
    address: "addr2"
    port: "port2"
```

and to concatenate them like above.

I have a ugly solution that goes like this:

```
# register the output of the facts to something I know
elasticache_facts:
  region: "{{ terraform.region }}"
  name: "{{ cluster }}-{{ env }}"
register: elasticache

#declare an empty var in vars file to be used as accumulator
memcache_hosts: ""

# iterate through the list of nodes and append the fields to my string; I will have some extra spaces(separators) but that's ok
set_fact:
  memcache_hosts: "{{ memcache_hosts }} {{item.endpoint.address}}:{{item.endpoint.port}}"
with_items: "{{ elasticache.elasticache_clusters[0].cache_nodes}}"
```

Is there some less ugly way to filter the list to the desired format?

Maybe there is a magic filter I don't know about?

I can also obtain two lists, one with hosts, one with ports, zip them, make a dict out of that, but I found only some ugly to_json and then regex to make it a string.
I am also considering to write a custom filter in python, but seems also overdoing it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two ways to achieve what you are looking for:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook
---
- name: Lets munge some data
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_list:
    - address: '10.0.0.0'
      port: '80' 
    - address: '10.0.0.1'
      port: '88' 
  tasks:
  - name: Quicky and dirty inline jinja2
    debug: 
      msg: "{% for item in my_list %}{{ item.address }}:{{ item.port }}{% if not loop.last %} {% endif %}{% endfor %}"

  # Note the to_json | from_json workaround for https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27299
  - name: Using JSON Query
    vars:
      jmes_path: "join(':', [address, port])"
    debug: 
      msg: "{{ my_list | to_json | from_json | map('json_query', jmes_path) | join(' ') }}"
```

The above outputs:

```
PLAY [Lets munge some data] **********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Quicky and dirty inline jinja2] ************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "10.0.0.0:80 10.0.0.1:88"
}

TASK [Using JSON Query] **************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "10.0.0.0:80 10.0.0.1:88"
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
It works perfectly!
The first looks very straight forward and readable. I will go with that one. I am a bit ashamed I did not find it myself. I knew there was some raw jinja2 formatting but was not sure on the syntax. I wrote a python filter instead because..."golden tool" complex I guess. But this is clearly more elegant.
The second seems pure dark magic:) I am reading know the link you provided for the to_json | from_json.
All the best!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upvote you:
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."